# Libgdx null Pointer

Tags: nullpointerexception, libgdx, box2d

I´m working on a Box2D Jump and run game and want the player to be teleported to the start when he hits a spike, but when he hits the spike, I get a null pointer exception.

Heres my Contact class:

```
public class WorldContactListener implements ContactListener {

Player player;

@Override
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
    Fixture fixA = contact.getFixtureA();
    Fixture fixB = contact.getFixtureB();
    player = new Player();

    int cDef = fixA.getFilterData().categoryBits | fixB.getFilterData().categoryBits;

    switch (cDef) {
        case HardwareRunner.PLAYER_BIT | HardwareRunner.BRICK_BIT:
        case HardwareRunner.PLAYER_BIT | HardwareRunner.SPIKE_BIT:
            player.die();

    }
}
```

And heres the part of my player class:

```
public void definePlayer(){
    bdef.position.set(32 / runner.PPM, (6 * 32) / runner.PPM);
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    b2body = world.createBody(bdef);

    FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    Vector2[] vertice = new Vector2[4];
    vertice[0] = new Vector2(-13, 13).scl(1 / runner.PPM);
    vertice[1] = new Vector2(13, 13).scl(1 / runner.PPM);
    vertice[2] = new Vector2(13, -13).scl(1 / runner.PPM);
    vertice[3] = new Vector2(-13, -13).scl(1 / runner.PPM);
    shape.set(vertice);
    shape.getRadius();
    fdef.filter.categoryBits = HardwareRunner.PLAYER_BIT;
    fdef.filter.maskBits =
            HardwareRunner.GROUND_BIT |
            HardwareRunner.COIN_BIT |
            HardwareRunner.BRICK_BIT |
            HardwareRunner.ENEMY_BIT |
            HardwareRunner.SPIKE_BIT |
            HardwareRunner.ENEMY_HEAD_BIT |
            HardwareRunner.ITEM_BIT;

    fdef.shape = shape;
    fdef.friction = .1f;
    b2body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData(this);
    fdef.isSensor = true;

    b2body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData(this);
}

public void die() {
    world.destroyBody(b2body);

    bdef.position.set(32 / runner.PPM, (6 * 32) / runner.PPM);
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    b2body = world.createBody(bdef);

    FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    Vector2[] vertice = new Vector2[4];
    vertice[0] = new Vector2(-13, 13).scl(1 / runner.PPM);
    vertice[1] = new Vector2(13, 13).scl(1 / runner.PPM);
    vertice[2] = new Vector2(13, -13).scl(1 / runner.PPM);
    vertice[3] = new Vector2(-13, -13).scl(1 / runner.PPM);
    shape.set(vertice);
    shape.getRadius();
    fdef.filter.categoryBits = HardwareRunner.PLAYER_BIT;
    fdef.filter.maskBits =
            HardwareRunner.GROUND_BIT |
                    HardwareRunner.COIN_BIT |
                    HardwareRunner.BRICK_BIT |
                    HardwareRunner.ENEMY_BIT |
                    HardwareRunner.SPIKE_BIT |
                    HardwareRunner.ENEMY_HEAD_BIT |
                    HardwareRunner.ITEM_BIT;

    fdef.shape = shape;
    fdef.friction = .1f;
    b2body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData(this);
    fdef.isSensor = true;

    b2body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData(this);
}
```

And the error is:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
at de.tobls.hardwarerunner.Sprites.Player.die(Player.java:223)
at de.tobls.hardwarerunner.Tools.WorldContactListener.beginContact(WorldContactListener.java:27)
at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.beginContact(World.java:982)
at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.jniStep(Native Method)
at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.step(World.java:686)
at de.tobls.hardwarerunner.Screens.PlayScreen.update(PlayScreen.java:112)
at de.tobls.hardwarerunner.Screens.PlayScreen.render(PlayScreen.java:127)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at de.tobls.hardwarerunner.HardwareRunner.render(HardwareRunner.java:71)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:215)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not **destroy the worlds items in asynchronous methods** - notice that contact listeners's methods are asynchronous.

The proper way to destroy the body od to mark it and then destroy right before **world.update()**

```
    //in asynchronous method 
    body.setUserData("DESTROY");

    //when rendering
    for(Body body : world.getBodies())
            if(body.getUserData().equals("DESTROY")) world.destroyBody(body);
```

**But** on the top of this - I see that you are doing nothing but moving the body when die so **why not to use setTransform method then**

```
    body.setTransform(new Vector2(newX, newY), body.getAngle() );
```

Instead of removing body and creating it again in a new position

Comment: I did that but I still get that error. What can I do against that error?

Comment: Please point out the line where error is - I see in stacktrace number of linę but no code

Comment: the error is in the line:  world.destroyBody(b2body); I think the problem is at b2body because no matter what I write in die() what has to do with the b2body I get that error

Comment: Have you called definePlayer before calling die ?

Comment: Yes i did it when starting to play

Comment: the problem is that I get an error when I make anythig with the body. What can I do??